# I have some addresses in column A which is not in proper format, I want to copy the state in separate cells

Tags: excel, match, formula

I have some 30000 addresses in Column A, which is not in proper format.

I have made a column of all States in Column C, whose range is from C2:C36.

I want something like that, those words in Column A that match with Column C whose range is C2:C36; should copy in Column B.

You can see the screenshot to understand better.
[image]

Please provide me solution, either any formula or VBA macro.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a formula version, you could try:-

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($C$2:$C$36,MATCH(TRUE,(ISNUMBER(FIND($C$2:$C$36,A2))),0)),"")
```

Is an array formula and must be entered in B2 using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>

This is case sensitive: for a non-case-sensitive version, use SEARCH instead of FIND.